# I want to create a new command for the nodes like the standard edit and delete

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

In drupal you have the standard commands edit and delete which you access typing :

```
node/99/edit
node/99/delete
```

I want to create some other commands like :

```
node/99/approve
node/99/test
...
```

Where do I hook to access the command and execute some code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) to define the path, coupled with the [`MENU_LOCAL_TASK`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_LOCAL_TASK/7) type, e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['node/%node/approve'] = array(
    'title' => 'Approve',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'access arguments' => array('my custom args'),
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_approve_node_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'weight' => -1 // Controls the display order for the tab
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Then you just implement a callback function, which has the node passed as a parameter, and build up your page output:

```
function MYMODULE_approve_node_page($node) {
  // Do something with $node...
  $build = array(
    '#markup' => node_view($node, 'teaser')
  );

  return $build;
}
```

Once you clear Drupal's caches you should see the new tab appear alongside the View/Edit tabs on a node page, but only for those users who have the permission you define in your `access arguments`.